# Upload image in firebase expo react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

i have an issue, i trying solve a several hours but white not success, my issue consists in create an upload to firestorage in firebase and show your respective uri in a variable i called image, but i don't know what wrong in my code, why he save my image like this [image: saved image]

and don't show you uri in my variable

bellow is my code

This is a create user i set here in imageUri a uploadImage who i called in my variable image

```
const createUser = async () => {
    const imageUri = uploadImage()
    await addDoc(
      usersCollectionRef,
      {
        name: name || null,
        cep: cep || null,
        logradouro: logradouro || null,
        numero: numero || null,
        bairro: bairro || null,
        uf: uf || null,
        image: imageUri || null,
      },      
      navigation.navigate("HomeScreen")
    );
  };
```

here is a code i pick image and my upload function to set a image in firestore (i follow the docs)

```
   const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });
    console.log(result);
    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImage(result);
    }
  };

  const uploadImage = () => {
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${image.name}`);
    uploadBytes(storageRef, image).then((snapshot) => {
      console.log(snapshot);
    });
  };
```

i really need some help for solve this issue i appreciate every tryed of help, any more questions about my code please comment if need i send my repository.

Comment: Can you also share what is the documentation that you followed?

Comment: this documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

Comment: You can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/71629397/upload-image-with-expo-and-firebase-cloud-storage) for reference on "Upload Image with Expo and Firebase Cloud Storage".

Comment: I apreciate the comment but did't work for me a tryng base me on this post but now i have another error this error: [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: storageRef.put is not a function. (In 'storageRef.put(fileBlob, metadata)', 'storageRef.put' is undefined)]

Comment: I suggest that you post another question for your new error, and be sure to link this current post to it in order for the community to best assist you.

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes in your code.

First, the ImagePicker returns an object like that ([docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/)) :

```
{
  "cancelled":false,
  "height":1611,
  "width":2148,
"uri":"file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/cropped1814158652.jpg"
}
```

There is no "name" field, that's why you see that undefined, because you access ${image.name}.

Second, as far as ImagePicker returns an object, you can't use it on uploadBytes pretending it is a Blob or similar. You should create a Blob from the uri image:

```
const response = await fetch(imageUri)
const blobFile = await response.blob()
```

Definetely, this is a function I suggest you to use for uploading an image on firebase storage

```
export async function uploadImage(imageUri) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(imageUri)
    const blobFile = await response.blob()

    const reference = ref(storage, "your_name.jpg")
    const result = await uploadBytes(reference, blobFile)
    const url = await getDownloadURL(result.ref)

    return url
  } catch (err) {
    return Promise.reject(err)
}
```

}